# Generate a download or show an error message in Wicket

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-6

I'm using the following code to dynamically generate a download in Wicket, using the `ResourceLink` approach (since the download is not a static file, it needs to be generated on the fly, and I was told this was the correct approach):

```
IResource res = new AbstractResource() {

    @Override
    protected ResourceResponse newResourceResponse(Attributes attributes) {
        ResourceResponse resourceResponse = new ResourceResponse();
        resourceResponse.setContentType("application/pdf");
        resourceResponse.setFileName("output.pdf");
        resourceResponse.setContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.ATTACHMENT);
        resourceResponse.setWriteCallback(new WriteCallback() {

            @Override
            public void writeData(Attributes attributes) throws IOException {
                OutputStream outputStream = attributes.getResponse().getOutputStream();
                try {
                    outputStream.write(generateDocument());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //Generation failed... Here I'd like to either show a popup message or alter the current page to show an error somewhere in the page
                }                       
            }
        });
        return resourceResponse;
    }   
};

ResourceLink<Void> resLink = new ResourceLink<Void>("resLink", res);
myForm.add(resLink);
```

The comment in the code above shows where I'm having trouble. If the generation of the download fails (which can happen, if certain conditions are not met) I'd like to show an error message, either by showing a popup or altering the page to show some error text (but in either case I want to avoid leaving/reloading the entire page)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the link with the answer:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/AJAX+update+and+file+download+in+one+blow

Don't forger to use a try/catch with an **error(e.getMessage())** inside the catch and a **target.add(feedbackPanel)** after catching the error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is possible because you need to use non-Ajax request to be able to download as ATTACHMENT. But since it is non-Ajax request you will need to either reload the current page or redirect to another page in case of an error.

Comment: What about the other way around? Can I use an Ajax component to dynamically generate a download?

Comment: For this see: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/AJAX+update+and+file+download+in+one+blow . But IMO this won't work for your use case too because it is not possible to stream the binary data in the Ajax response and it works with a redirect.